# How do I get PC and PS5 audio to play through both speakers and headset simultaneously while being able to switch seamlessly between headset/speakers?

Tags: audio, desktop-computer, speakers, headset, playstation

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I want to be able to hear:

PC and PS5 audio simultaneously through my headset.

OR

PC and PS5 audio simultaneously through my speakers.

And effectively switch between both.

I currently have my speakers plugged into my monitor (24G2U) and since my PC and PS5 are connected to my monitor, I can play audio from one device at a time. I am using Windows 10 and the PS5 doesn't have a line in/out on the console.

Comment: Please [edit] in a way the question makes sense, some at least.

Comment: Can you please let us know what operating system you are using?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid The OS isn't relevant here. The OS doesn't control the monitor to which both the PC and the PS5 (BTW, off-topic here) are connected (supposedly by HDMI or DP) . And, obviously, unless the monitor itself allows mixing 2 audio sources without changing the video input as well (it doesn't, no monitor I know does) all of this makes no sense, at all.

Comment: The OS is definitely relevant if you want software solutions. Otherwise, go buy a hardware mixer.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid There are no software solutions, that's the point :) No software from the PC or the PS5 can instruct the AOC monitor to toggle audio from its other input. We both can make an educated guess about about what this (very young and naïve) person wants and we both should know that's simply not possible.

Comment: It is probably easiest to use a hardware mixer for this. But, there is possibly software that may do this as well, but this will be dependent on multiple factors, like the drivers and available inputs and outputs, and not just the software itself, bringing us back to a hardware mixer being the likely best solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is both hardware, and software. For the hardware you will need a 3.5mm audio cable. Since you refused to provide any info on which OS you are using, I am going to assume its Windows.

## Hardware part of the solution:

- The audio will be piped from the PS5 via HDMI cable to your 24G2U monitor, which has an audio out 3.5mm jack. From there you will pipe the audio from the monitor to your PC audio input using the 3.5mm cable. This will connect to the audio in 3.5mm input on your motherboard or soundcard.
- Next is some Windows Sound configuration. Go into the Windows Sound control panel, find Line-in under the recording tab, and then go into 'properties' and make sure “listen to this device” is enabled. This will essentially allow you to hear what is coming in from the input on the soundcard.

## Software part of the solution:

Since you requested a way to toggle between headphones and speakers, a software method is required, unless your setup is entirely hardware.

Now that you have audio being piped into your PC from the PS5 via the soundcard's input, the next step is to configure your outputs. An easy way to do this is to use a free Windows Utility called [SoundSwitch](https://soundswitch.aaflalo.me/), which allows you to set up various audio configurations with the ability to set up different profiles and assign hotkeys to toggle them.

To do so, simply navigate to Settings, then the Profiles tab. Here you can set up one profile for your headphones output, and another for your speakers. All profiles have the ability to assign a hotkey:
[image]